# Clean Beautiful Soup output from unwanted span

Tags: html, text, beautifulsoup

I am reading `HTML` using `Beautiful Soup`. I have ran the command `soup.find_all("span",{"class":"budget-list__data__number budget-list__number show-for-medium"})` and obtain:

```html
[<span class="budget-list__data__number budget-list__number show-for-medium">
      4 000 €

      <span class="project-votes display-inline-block">24 <span class="text-uppercase text-small">votes</span></span>
</span>, <span class="budget-list__data__number budget-list__number show-for-medium">
      25 000 €

      <span class="project-votes display-inline-block">24 <span class="text-uppercase text-small">votes</span></span>
</span>, <span class="budget-list__data__number budget-list__number show-for-medium">
      14 000 €

      <span class="project-votes display-inline-block">23 <span class="text-uppercase text-small">votes</span></span>
</span>, <span class="budget-list__data__number budget-list__number show-for-medium">
      35 000 €
      
     .
     .
     .
```

I am interested in keeping only the elements that include monetary amounts (e.g: 4 000 euros, etc) but ignoring the bits of code included in `<span class="project-votes display-inline-block">`. I thought about using `span.clear()` but that does not do the trick. Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
spans = soup.find_all(
    "span",
    {"class": "budget-list__data__number budget-list__number show-for-medium"},
)

for span in spans:
    print(span.contents[0].strip())
```

Prints:

```
4 000 €
25 000 €
14 000 €
35 000 €
```